# How to do parallel-processing with fftw3 library?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, fftw

I need to parallel processing for fftw3. I wrote a function which has fftw3 plan. And i tried to parallelized this function with multi-threading. I don't want to make the FFT code block multithreaded. I want to make whole class multithreaded. However it gives an error when thread is greater than "1": `Signal: SIGFPE (Arithmetic exception)` . It aborted during `fftw_execute(my_plan);`. There is no problem when number of thread is equal to 1.

My fft code as below:

```
fftw_complex *input = nullptr, *output = nullptr;

input = (fftw_complex *) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * frameLengthSamples);
output = (fftw_complex *) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * Nfft);

fftw_plan my_plan;
void fftw_plan_with_nthreads(int nthreads=1);
my_plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(Nfft, input, output, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

for (int j = 0; j < frameLengthSamples; j++) {
    input[j][0] = x(j, i);
    input[j][1] = 0;
}

fftw_execute(my_plan);

for (int j = 0; j < Nfft; j++) {
    std::complex<double> fft_val(static_cast<double>(output[j][0]), static_cast<double>(output[j][1]));
    X(j, i) = fft_val;
}

fftw_destroy_plan(my_plan);
fftw_free(input);
fftw_free(output);
```

Edit: For example, I have 2 wav file and i want to process them at the same time. I don't want to make multithread for one file.

Comment: Is this the real code?  It looks like fairly standard fftw3 code albeit with the function declaration `void fftw_plan_with_nthreads(int nthreads=1);` in the middle of it.  And I don't see any use of threads.

Comment: You need to call `fftw_init_threads()` before `fftw_plan_with_nthreads`.

Comment: This is standart code. I use this in a class and i tried to make it multithread. I don't want to make multithread FFT code block. Because of this i wrote a thread function which calls this standart function. I edited question.